# How to getting started wit AWS IoT in RPi like a beginner?

Tags: electronics, amazon

I have being follow the steps from Amazon Officials pages to connect the Raspberry Pi to AWS IoT cloud, that's working fine but my main concern is to how to write a code to start interfacing with sensors? Like Digital Inputs and Outputs.

Do you know any resource that show you how to start to interface with AWS IoT in such a way to read inputs from the RPi? How to send commands to the make HIGH a led?

I think I may be very directly with my question but I wanna see if you know some methods to start to work with the AWS IoT cloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Due to Raspbian support Python 2&3, you can check online documents about AWS SDK for Python to start your coding. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/iot-api.pdf 
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/blob/master/README.rst 
But for beginners, I suggest that before you start to approach the Amazon AWS, you should try on

> CloudMQTT

and make a simple project like :

> **"turn the LED on/off"**

or

> **"turn the LED on if the temperature is above 30 Celcius degrees"** *(which use Arduino UNO to support you)*